# vuejs is using a modified event directive without an event handler OK?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

In the following snippet, `fireCheck` captures clicks on the `<li>` and toggles the enclosed checkbox.

On the checkbox I have a click listener modified to stop event bubbling up to parent elements (which prevents the enclosing `<li>`'s click handler from firing and throwing an error) but nothing to actually handle the checkbox's click event.

```
<li v-for="datum in data" @click="fireCheck($event)">
    <input @click.stop type="checkbox" v-model="datum.checked" v-bind:value="data.name"/>
</li>
```

I did this as a hail mary and it produces no errors in the current versions of  the major browsers. Is this bad?

Answer (score 0):

*Is it bad?* Well, yes and no. As far as I can tell, your input remains accessible through the keyboard (even if screenreaders cannot find any information on what that checkbox may be) and your model remains reactive.

That said, you are reinventing the wheel. A label html element links a form field with a description. It also catches clicks, and depending on the type of form field, focuses the form field, toggles it or opens a file dialog. You should really be using that instead of your own implementation.

```
<li v-for="datum in data">
  <label>
    <span class="screen-reader">{{ datum.name }}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="datum.checked" :value="datum.name">
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: doing above and setting label width to 100% is the solution. thanks